# elasticsearch aggregation with filter from query

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, aggregation

I'm new to elasticsearch and forgive if my question would be commonplace.  I use ElasticSearch v2.2. The next query

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "multi_match": {
                    "query": "nokia",
                    "fields": [
                        "*.right",
                        "*.correct_keyboard_layout"
                    ],
                    "fuzziness": "AUTO"
                }
            },
            "filter": [
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "brands": ["Nokia"]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "models_id": ["2432", "5234"]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "stores": ["999"]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "filtered": {
            "aggs": {
                "models_id": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "models_id",
                        "size": 0
                    }
                },
                "category_id": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "category_id",
                        "size": 0
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get in the aggregation result, excluding the filter from the request (that is, through all the records that match the query "Nokia", but I just need answers on these models, and in aggregation in response lists all models), although here
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_filtering_queries_and_aggregations.html
It says that the filter should be taken out of the request, and It do not understand why I do not work.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show how you are sending your query?

Comment: I use a plugin for Laravel Elasticquent. But with curl my back the same record.
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/my_index/products' -d 'json shown above'